# Should I worry that my advisor will get sick of being a professor and move to industry?

Tags: advisor

My advisor is a first year professor (in CS) and he seems really busy and stressed all the time.  Before becoming a professor, he was in industry, where he probably had to do a lot less work and could spend more time with his family.  Should I worry that he'll move back to industry in a year or two because he's decided being a professor is not for him?

Comment: That is a concern for any PhD student. If you are comfortable talking to him, it is probably worth having a conversation about your concerns.

Comment: Note that if he does leave, the department will try to find you another advisor who is working on similar topics so you don't have to change your research... so outside of making sure you're on good terms with the other professors, this may not be worth worrying about.

Comment: I would be more concerned that he will leave involuntarily.  He probably worked very hard to get his position, so he won't give it up casually.

Comment: @keshlam This is not the case in all universities.

Comment: @xLeitix: I'll take your word for it. In that case, the first thing to do is to find out what ***is*** the policy in that university. Begin by finding out whether the worry is misplaced.

Comment: Why are you asking this question here, on this site, instead of asking asking your professor directly? What makes you think that we know anything of what your professor is up to, and that we know more than you do without asking him?

Comment: @keshlam I would expect any departing advisor to help their own students find new advisors, directly and personally, rather than relying on "the department" to do it for them.

Comment: @JeffE: Agreed, but if he doesn't than I would hope that any decently run department would.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I worry that he'll move back to industry in a year or two because he's decided being a professor is not for him?

This is probably not worth worrying about, although it could happen.  Computer scientists who leave industry for academia generally really want to be in academia and don't often return to industry quickly.

If you're concerned, one way to get a feeling for his perspective is to ask him about his experience with industrial and academic jobs.  This is a very natural question, since he knows both sides well and this information is relevant to your own future plans.  You could follow up by asking him how he chose academia over industry if he leaves that vague.  If he sounds unhappy with his decision, you could ask whether he thinks he might return to industry someday.  I bet this conversation will reassure you that he wants to be in academia, and at least you'll find out if your fears are justified.

Incidentally, I'm skeptical that computer scientists in industry have a lot less work and spend more time with their families.  The ones I've met spend their time a little differently than academics do but seem rather busy as well.

Comment: Or, insad of skirting around the issue, you could just **ask him directly**, as though you and he were actual adult human beings. I recommend the following wording: "You seem stressed. Should I be worried that you migt move to industry?"

Comment: Asking directly is certainly simplest given a good enough relationship, but it's important to make sure it couldn't come across as an insult.  Someone who thinks they might be unable or unwilling to supervise graduate students in a year or two has no business recruiting Ph.D. students, and so it would be best to phrase the question delicately.  Otherwise it could across like "Do you think taking an academic job might have been a career mistake that could lead you to throw me under the bus in a year or two?"

Comment: If your advisor finds the question insulting, you want a new advisor anyway.

Comment: The last paragraph matches my experience. I found being a PhD student positively relaxing compared to my prior industry job.